# Invalid Input when trying to configure lambda blueprint iot-button-email

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, iot

I'm trying to use tha AWS Lambda Blueprint iot-button-email. Apparently it does not accept the serial number, even if I'm quite sure it is correct:
[image]
This prevent creating the lambda. What am I doing wrong?

**workaround**

> By creating an empty lambda ( ie pressing remove ) and then creating a rule
>   from the "thing" in the registry it is possible to achieve the desired result as well. Maybe the problem was my thing already be registered?

Answer (score -1):

As of today, that bug has been fixed by Amazon!
Configuration should now work fine.

There is a post in the amazon forum:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=257887
Where ist says, it was a technical problem, which is now fixed.